# Twilio Faxing Protected Asset

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to use the faxing service to fax a document that I uploaded to the twilio assets using the api. When I upload the document as a public file, the faxing works, but if I upload it was a protected asset, it gives me an error of "Parameter 'MediaUrl' is invalid". Is there a way so that I could fax a protected asset.

Thanks,

Jason

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your post

Answer (score 0):

Protected assets are accessible only from Twilio Functions. You can sign up for the Twilio Functions/AssetsV2 UI, which offers a protected asset, that verifies a Twilio Signature header before providing access to the Asset (which the Twilio Fax Webhook should present).

[Get Early Access](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeA4tyKS005r_WwVgOFfP6beyE58UIHRGZNAvpLrPGxQUhlWw/viewform)

[Functions V2 Editor Early Access](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions-v2-editor-early-access)